# How to return a div in <a href> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have this code on a page:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remont_price_link">Потолок + </a>
```

[image]
I need my code to show a div just like in '1'. '2' - how it should be BEFORE the click.

So I need to popup of div 'remont_price_link' when user click on 
This one doesn't work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)onclick='popup' ;" class="remont_price_link">Потолок + </a>
```

Sorry for silly.

[image]

Comment: Is `popup` the function that does what you want to acheive?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is. I just need to return div just like on '1' in pic after the click. Before click ot should be hidden like in '2'.

Comment: Post the code of `popup` function. Plus you have a slight error there the link should be: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remont_price_link" onclick="popup()">Потолок + </a>`

Comment: thx. but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the code of `popup` function?

Comment: It says 'popup is not defined'. Omg I thought it is a standart utility function in JS.

Comment: I didnt write popup function so far. That's why it doesn't work. Thanks for help me understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135544/discussion-between-ratibor-yaroslavovich-and-ibrahim-mahrir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this tou your script:

```
$(".remont_price_link").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var spoiler = $(this).closest(".remont_price_item").find(".spoiler-text");
    if(parent.hasClass("folded")) {
        parent.removeClass("folded");
        spoiler.show();
    }
    else {
        parent.addClass("folded");
        spoiler.hide();
    }
});
```

And keep the links as they are. Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remont_price_link">Потолок + </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show/hide your div using css 'display' and javascript.

See code here: https://codepen.io/cpenarrieta/pen/XpoExe

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Javascript

```
function showDiv() {
  var x=document.getElementById("divId");
  if (x.classList.contains("show")) {
    x.classList.add('hidden');
    x.classList.remove('show');
  } else if (x.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    x.classList.add('show');
    x.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='showDiv();'>Потолок +</a>
<div id="divId" class="hidden">
div content
</div>
```